# No audio/sound while playing .mkv movie on VideView

Tags: android, android-videoview, video-player

I'm working on android video player using VideoView. It plays all formats songs like mp4, 3gp and mkv. But when I play a movie having .mkv extension its still working fine but I can't hear its sound. Can you guys please help me like how to fix the problem for mkv files to pitch its sound?

Comment: missing codec probably...

Comment: I noticed the same problem for a specific android device, I need integrate another player library(a lot of work) to play it with sound.